# IOS Not Recognizing Media Queries and Certain CSS Styles

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, media-queries

I'm not a very experienced developer by any means, so these issues may have resolutions that are more obvious to you than me.

The site I'm developing is [ion123.com](http://www.ion123.com).

I've been using my LG G4 for mobile testing. Site looks great on that particular device. Looks like butt on Safari, iPhones, and iPads. Seems like IOS isn't picking up my media queries at all, and I *am* using the viewport tag in the head section.

It's also not picking up styling for certain elements. For example, the left sidebar buttons on the [Solutions](http://www.ion123.com/solutions.html) page.

I would really appreciate some guidance here. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding this into your head tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> . Would be easier if I could enter your website, but since I'm in China now the internet is very bad here.

Comment: Yeah, I have that added. Thanks, though.

Comment: Just noticed a second ago my bad.

Comment: No worries. That's the solution I've seen help most people out. Seems like that's not the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with your main_style.css file. Try running through https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and a few errors will come up that other browsers are ok with but safari fail on.

- You have a number of keyframe animations that are incomplete, you should fix them or remove them (ln 234-237, 240-243, 258-261)
- Ln 252 letter spacing doesn't have a valid value. Should have a 'px' after 1.2
- Ln 355 random '/' character should be removed.

Once these issues were fixed the website started displaying correctly on my iOS devices and Safari (on desktop)

Comment: Wow. Deleting those keyframe animations did the trick. Why exactly would those have completely screwed up the entire layout for IOS?

Thanks a lot, by the way, for taking the time to look into this for me.

Comment: The incomplete keyframe animations were causing a parse errors that safari wasn't able to ignore like other browsers. So basically safari stopped reading the css once it encountered the issues, which is why it seemed to completely ignore your media queries.  You should also fix the other 2 issues if you haven't as they are also causing your css to be invalid, which could lead to other issues.

Comment: Great. No worries. Feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Of course. I guess I need 15 points or some crap to make your answer a publicly accepted.